# Error while changing Font-size of UIAlertAction's button title of UIAlertController using Swift in iOS

Tags: swift, ios9, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

```
let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let customActionButton: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Custom", style: .Default) { action -> Void in

}
let attrString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "Custom", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.init(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 17.0)!])
customActionButton.setValue(attrString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
alertController.addAction(customActionButton)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**I got the below error:**

> '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _attributedTitle.'

Please let me know what should be the proper key value for changing the Font-size of UIAlertAction button title.

Any help is appreciated..!!

Comment: It is attributedTitle not _attributedTitle. Also it is used to give attributed title not atttibuted action.

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala I also used attributedTitle but not fix that issue :(

Comment: That is for AlertController title not for action

Comment: If you want to change the button title color it is possible using alertVC.view.tintColor = your color;

Comment: OP wants to change the font family and size of the `UIAlertAction`, not color.

Comment: I want to change font-size

Comment: It is not currently possible.

Comment: Any alternate solution for that?

Comment: Try to use custom alert view. Search about this on google you will find it